# Installed libinput-gestures to have mac-like gestures but it is not working for some reason

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, xps, libinput, gestures

new to Ubuntu and to Linux in general. 
I installed libinput-gestures, following these [instructios](https://medium.com/@kaigo/mac-like-gestures-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-15-7ea6e3be7f76).
Everything went smoothly (I am assuming, as I got no errors) and the GUI worked without any problems. I added the gestures included in the tutorial and restarted my XPS13 but nothing happens when I perform the gestures. What am I missing? Your help is much appreciated.

Edit to add system details: 
Using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS installed on a Dell XPS13

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for the info! Added the details.

Comment: What do you see if you execute `evemu-describe | grep INPUT` against your touchpad?

Comment: @Hi-Angel deleted my edit. I meant xdotool was not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your user to the input group first. `sudo gpasswd -a $USER input`

xdotool was not installed. That is why the gestures were not working. `sudo apt install xdotool` to install it.

The [guide](https://medium.com/@kaigo/mac-like-gestures-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-15-7ea6e3be7f76) is updated.

Comment: Btw, [the official documentation mentions these steps](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures#installation). Although it looks a bit boring without the screenshots. I wonder if the project owner would accept a contribution that adds some screenshots…

Answer (score 0):

The key-combos in the guide did not work for me.
I eventually did get something that worked. My config file looks like this.

```
gesture swipe up 3 xdotool key 'Super_L+s'
gesture swipe down 3 xdotool key 'Super_L+s'
gesture swipe right 3 xdotool key 'Super_L+Prior'
gesture swipe left 3 xdotool key 'Super_L+Next'
```

I am using a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 20.